# 'Popular mathematics' resource about infinite ordinals

Tags: reference-request, ordinals, book-recommendation, popular-math

The 'popular mathematics' literature (think Martin Gardner, William Dunham, Hofstadter, and the like) abounds with material on the mathematics of infinite **cardinals**, starting - and quite often ending - with Cantor's uncountability proof(s). You can't turn round in that section of a bookshop without bumping into a diagonalisation argument, or [Hilbert's quote](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/David_Hilbert) about paradise.

But what I've never seen, and what I would like to see, is similarly-pitched material about infinite **ordinals**. At the risk of being hand-wavey, if you can imagine an article about cardinals starting approximately

> Let's define cardinality by {explanation}, and explore what happens if we
>   extend the idea to infinite sets; give the name $\aleph_0$ to the
>   cardinality of $\mathbb N$, and off we go

then I'd like to see something starting

> We know how to count $1, 2, 3$. Now let's say that there's something
>   called $\omega$ that's {explanation}, and off we go

My specific motivation is to get some kind of *intuition* for what's going on in the proof of [Goodstein's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodstein%27s_theorem), but of course all knowledge is its own reward...

Comment: I don't know any popular books about ordinals. My "pitch" is to imagine a line to the bathroom in a party, first someone is using the toilet, and then someone is waiting and someone after that guy, and some other people, etc. $\omega$ is when the line is infinitely long, but every person in the line has only finitely many people before them. Then comes $\omega+1$, which as the previous line, with one additional guy after all those infinitely many people. Not only he will have to wait infinitely long before using the toilet, I don't want to have to imagine the smell either! Poor him!

Comment: Rudy Rucker's Infinity and the Mind contains and excellent chapter on the countable ordinals.

Comment: Infinity only gets interesting when you are talking about different orders of infinity. After you cover Cantor's diagonal proof, what more is there to be said that would capture the public's imagination? It is a very specialized interest.

Comment: PBS's Infinite Series now has a video that brings up countable ordinals with illustrations: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uWwUpEY4c8o